# Will Allah forgive me for this?

Tags: sin, forgiveness, tawba

I am a girl, age of 13 and I have been crying a lot and I've been so worried. I am learning how to perform the 2 Raka'at (2 units)
and 4 Raka'at.

I have also been lying a lot and I am starting to repent and turn to Allah. I have been worried so much, I've been crying for a long time.

Am I allowed to pray in order to forgive my sins?
Please answer, I am so worried. I told my mum that I was afraid of going to hell and I've been crying so much.

I also learnt about how you must not hurt Allah's servants, and that you must apologise and ask for forgiveness. If they say no, Allah can not forgive you.

However, when I was about 3-5 years old, I slapped a young child because he was in my way and I deeply regret my actions. Does the sin count, and can Allah still forgive me?

I regret all the sins I have committed and I worry about this all the time. Please someone answer me, I do not want to go to hell.

Please inshallah I really want to go to heaven.

Answer (score 0):

Allah is most gracious most merciful remember this as long as you regret the sin and repent and say I will not do it again ALLAH Insha’Allah will forgive you (for third party) if that person dosent forgive you their is till HOPE you tried keep making dua for that person and ask ALLAH to forgive you It Allah forgives all sins but if you die in the state of shirk and not repenting to Allah then Allah cannot forgive that And he will forgive all other sins to whom he wishes.